# Spacing problems

Tags: support, mathjax

I am experiencing problems with spacing too short after equations. For example, if there is a comma just after an inlined equation, sometimes it's shown just over the equation itself.

I have an example: [Finding mod of X^2+1 = 0 to have exacly 4 solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601365/finding-mod-of-x21-0-to-have-exacly-4-solutions/601379#601379) (look at the answer)

Is anybody having the same problem on this example? Or is it a problem with my navigator or my LaTeX code?

Comment: It might be the same problem as described in these older posts: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/editing-appears-to-affect-maths-display, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6338/a-small-problem-with-tex-rendering-after-an-edit and the other posts linked there.

Comment: Bigger than usual, it's exactly what I observed! I thought I had changed the zoom of Firefox by mistake. After reading a bit, it's definitely the same problem. Thank you! There does not seem to be a solution, but at least I don't feel alone. :-)

Comment: I recall having seen this effect immediately after posting or editing an answer. Reloading the page got rid of it every time. I'm using Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

Your example answer looks like the below for me.

[image]

I don't think the spacing looks too bad here. Are you worried that the $3$ in $13$ and the the comma after it are too close?

For reference to others, the pre-formatted answer is

```
The smallest solution is $m=130=2 \cdot 5\cdot 13$, with roots
of $x^2+1 \equiv 0 \pmod m$  being $\{47, 57, 73, 83\}$
```

and the formatted answer is

> The smallest solution is $m=130=2 \cdot 5\cdot 13$, with roots of $x^2+1 \equiv 0 \pmod m$  being $\{47, 57, 73, 83\}$

Comment: No it looks good. And after checking I have the same. I guess the navigator gets crazy sometimes (it's Firefox, not many problems usually). Sorry to have bothered you for just this!

Comment: Also I changed the tag, it's not a bug after all ;-)

Comment: If you get a similar problem in future, you might like to grab a screenshot and add it to your post. It also helps to give some details about the machine you're running and browser+version/plugins so that it's easier to identify where things are going wrong.